# What are the values of columns which are not set in a BEFORE UPDATE trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-5.5

According to MySQL

> In a before update trigger there are two mysql extensions viz NEW and
>   OLD to refer to the old and new column values of the updating row.

Say, my table is :

```
            create table foo ( id primary key auto_increment,
                           fname varchar(10),
                           lname varchar(10) 
                         );
```

**And I have inserted 1 row:**

```
            insert into foo (fname,lname) values ("Edam","Chuti");
```

**If I run an update like :**

```
            update foo set fname="Edam1" where id=1;
```

**Then in my before update trigger for this table what  will be the values of :**

```
            NEW.fname=?
            NEW.lname=?
```

Comment: What if you check before you ask?

Comment: @zerkms NEW.fname="Edam1" and NEW.lname="Chuti" . I checked it with the test database but it didn't make sense to me. so that I wanted to have some opinions from people.

Comment: So, If I don't set some columns then the new values of those unset columns are equal to the old values of those columns.

Comment: they are not "old values", they are the values "after `UPDATE` was performed"

Comment: After UPDATE was performed ? But I'm talking about the BEFORE UPDATE trigger. I don't get why after UPDATE is coming here.

Comment: BTW I have been expecting the NEW.col = NULL for any col that has not been set with value in update command. So that I could detect whether a column has been changed or not.

Comment: *NEW and OLD to refer to the old and new column values of the updating row*, the new column value of a column not affected by an update statement is the same as before the update, it's not NULL. But you could check with NEW.col <> OLD.col to check for a change.

Comment: What if the OLD.fname="Edam" and in update command it's again set fname="Edam" ? Here OLD.fname= NEW.fname. So I can't detect the change here. Can I?

Comment: Was there any change?
 - The trigger is executing, so an update on the table was performed;
 - OLD.fname = NEW.fname so it either was set to the same value or it wasn't specified in the query. Does it make a difference? Isn't not being set AND being set to the same value semantically equivalent?