# How to determine if a column value was passed in or not on the Update statement in a "Before Update" Trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want my trigger to be able to determine whether a field was actually assigned a value in the update statement so that if it was not, I can assign a value.

I looked at the following post and it talks about the same thing, but it doesn't say whether there is a way to determine whether a value was passed into the Update statement or not.

[What are the values of columns which are not set in a BEFORE UPDATE trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083724/what-are-the-values-of-columns-which-are-not-set-in-a-before-update-trigger)

Here's an example.  I have a table:

```
    CREATE TABLE Business (
    BusinessId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    IsActive TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    UpdateUser VARCHAR(66) DEFAULT NULL,
    UpdateDate DATETIME(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (BusinessId)
    );$$
```

And I have a Before Update trigger on that table.

If UpdateUser and UpdateDate aren't specified on the Update statement, then I want to set those values in the trigger to USER() and NOW().

Record 3 in my Business table looks like this:

```
    BusinessId = 3
    Name = 'Geronimo'
    IsActive = 1
    UpdateUser = 'Susie'
    UpdateDate = '2019-04-30 09:14'
```

Here's my update statement:
     Update Business Set Name = 'Test' Where BusinessId = 3;

Inside my trigger, NEW.UpdateUser = 'Susie' and OLD.UpdateUser = 'Susie'.
Likewise, NEW.UpdateDate = '2019-04-30 09:14' and OLD.UpdateDate = '2019-04-30 09:14'.

So, if NEW.UpdateUser always equals OLD.UpdateUser when UpdateUser isn't specified in the Update statement, how can I know whether the same user updated the record or whether the user wasn't passed into the Update statement?

In my example, both of these update statements produce the same trigger results:

```
 Update Business Set Name = 'Test' Where BusinessId = 3;
```

and

```
 Update Business Set Name = 'Test', UpdateUser='Susie' Where BusinessId = 3;
```

But I want the first update statement to set the UpdateUser to USER().  And the second update statement to set the UpdateUser to 'Susie'.

This was no problem with SQL Server, but in MySQL, I've not found a way to do this....